# How to initialize reference in class?

Tags: c#, ref

I need something like this

```
public class Displayer
{
    public ref string[] lines { get; set; }
}
```

But i didn't find any solution.
Full code of my "application" is:

```
 public class Displayer
{
    public ref string[] lines { get; set; }
    public async void Update()
    {
        while(true)
        {
           Console.Clear();
           foreach(string s in lines)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(s);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a ref? What do you think it will give you? How do you expect to use it?

Comment: @ClickRick, I need to use asynchronous method to display changes, which are done by changing int[] variable.

Comment: Add code to illustrate that, then. Oh, and try it without ref.

Comment: @ClickRick, updated

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, thanks, but it's just sample code. I just don't know how to add reference variable to class.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally wrong. Your Displayer class is unnecessarily updating console over and over. thousand times per second. that's not logical.

The right approach is to update console whenever needed. your property needs to be implemented in another way.

```
public class Displayer
{
    private string[] _lines;

    public string[] Lines
    {
        get { return _lines; }
        set
        {
            // while setting new value call Update
            _lines = value;
            Update();
        }
    }

    public async void Update()
    {
        // update console only once
        Console.Clear();

        foreach (string s in Lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be aware of changes inside your collection then use `ObservableCollection` instead.

You don't need to change the reference here. Since you can always change size of collection.

```
public class Displayer
{
    public Displayer()
    {
        Lines = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Lines.CollectionChanged += Update; // Update will be called automatically when ever collection changes.
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Lines { get; }

    private void Update(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // update console only once
        Console.Clear();

        foreach (string s in Lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```